# HTML Split/Merge cell issue

Tags: html, css

I try to display my output as table format and this is what I want my table looks like:

[image]

And for now I could make like following:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tbHead">Document No.</td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="documentId">${approva.documentId}</p></td>
    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Approval</td>

    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp0">${approva.docApp0}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp1">${approva.docApp1}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp2">${approva.docApp2}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp3">${approva.docApp3}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp4">${approva.docApp4}</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tbHead">Department</td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docDepartment">${approva.docDepartment}</p></td>

    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp0">${approva.docApp0}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp1">${approva.docApp1}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp2">${approva.docApp2}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp3">${approva.docApp3}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp4">${approva.docApp4}</p></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

However, when I change my code like following to make it looks like the first picture, it looks like following:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Document No.</td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="2"><p id="documentId">${approva.documentId}</p></td>
    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="4">Approval</td>

    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp0">${approva.docApp0}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp1">${approva.docApp1}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp2">${approva.docApp2}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp3">${approva.docApp3}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp4">${approva.docApp4}</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Department</td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="2"><p id="docDepartment">${approva.docDepartment}</p></td>

    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp0">${approva.docApp0}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp1">${approva.docApp1}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp2">${approva.docApp2}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp3">${approva.docApp3}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp4">${approva.docApp4}</p></td>
</tr>
```

[image]

What is the problem that my output does not look like what I expected?

FYI, both tbHead and tbContent have same value as their height.

I tried to give different class for cells with different height values, but it always follow other cell's height which has bigger height value.

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Document No.</td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="2"><p id="documentId">${approva.documentId}</p></td>
    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="4">Approval</td>

    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp0">${approva.docApp0}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp1">${approva.docApp1}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp2">${approva.docApp2}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp3">${approva.docApp3}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent"><p id="docApp4">${approva.docApp4}</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp0">${approva.docApp0}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp1">${approva.docApp1}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp2">${approva.docApp2}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp3">${approva.docApp3}</p></td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3"><p id="docApp4">${approva.docApp4}</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Department</td>
    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="2"><p id="docDepartment">${approva.docDepartment}</p></td>               
</tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.

Note that the empty td's need to be there or it will collapse looking like what you have already.

```css
table , td, th {
 border: 1px solid #595959;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
 padding: 3px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 25px;
}
td:last-child {
 border-right: 1px solid transparent;
 border-top: 1px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3">1</td>
   <td rowspan="3">2</td>
   <td rowspan="6">3</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>7</td>
   <td>8</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="5">4</td>
   <td rowspan="5">5</td>
   <td rowspan="5">6</td>
   <td rowspan="5">7</td>
   <td rowspan="5">8</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3">1</td>
   <td rowspan="3">2</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

*Side note:*

Making tables like this can be tricky, so this little online creator does a really good job:

- https://tabletag.net/

Comment: Thank you for your answer and info about useful website.  I just made three different table before you post this answer, but I will try it later.

Answer (score 0):

You define the TD elements in the table row they start. So the cells with 1, 2 and 3 in there would start in second row. Department and ahhhhhh.. would start in row 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did understand what you said, so I tried it, but unfortunately, it did not work well.  I did like what I updated above.  That is what you said, right?